# Functional gradient and inner product in machine learning

Tags: inner-products, machine-learning, gradient-descent, function-spaces

In several applications, such as machine learning, the following setup arises:

Let $V$ denote a function space equipped with the following inner product $ \langle f, g\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(x_{i}) g(x_{i}),$ where the functions are real-valued and we only observe the image of $x_{i}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,m.$ Now, define a functional $\ell : V \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\ell(f) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} l(y_{i},f(x_{i})),$ where the $y_{i}$ denote some fixed real numbers and $l$ is usually assumed to be convex and differentiable in the second argument, such as the quadratic error $l(y_{i},f(x_{i})) = (y_{i} -f(x_{i}))^{2}.$

Typically, this functional is treated as a function of $m$ real variables based on the right-hand side. So, the functional gradient is treated as an element of $\mathbb{R}^{m},$ i.e.,
$$\nabla \ell (f) = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \ell(f)}{\partial f(x_{1})} \\
\frac{\partial \ell(f)}{\partial f(x_{2})} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial \ell(f)}{\partial f(x_{m})}
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}.$$

Now, what I want to compute is $\sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{\partial \ell(f)}{\partial f(x_{i})} g(x_{i}).$ Can this be written as $ \langle \nabla \ell (f), g \rangle,$ or, do I need to consider the standard inner product, i.e., dot product, on $\mathbb{R}^{m},$ where $g$ would be a vector with components $g(x_{i})$ for $i=1,2,\dots,m?$

Part of my confusion with $ \langle \nabla \ell (f), g \rangle$ is that I don't know how to check the right-hand side of the definition: is $\nabla \ell (f)$ an element of $V?$

Of note, sometimes this is done with the Gateaux derivative, but I am less familiar with this type of derivative. Also, the main aim is to get to gradient descent, which explains the simplification to finite-dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think the Gateaux derivative is probably the best way to understand this.  But few people teach multivariable calculus so that Gateaux derivatives are an obvious generalization.  :(

The key point to understand is that derivatives aren't really a number, they're a *best linear approximant*.   In calculus, you usually see $$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\dots$$ where $f'(x_0)$ is a number.  In multivariable calculus, this turns into $$\vec{f}(\vec{x})=\vec{f}(\vec{x_0})+(\mathcal{D}\vec{f})(\vec{x_0})(\vec{x} - \vec{x_0})+\dots$$ where $(\mathcal{D}f)(x_0)$ is a matrix.  This is because, in each case, the derivative is trying to write $f$ as a constant plus a linear part.  A linear function from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$ is just multiplication by a number; a linear function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is multiplication by a matrix.

You've also seen in linear algebra that a matrix representation is always just a sort of convenience for arithmetic: the same transformation has different representations in different bases.  So maybe we should instead write that expansion in terms of the underlying linear transformation: $$\vec{f}(\vec{x})=\vec{f}(\vec{x_0})+\mathcal{D}(\vec{f})(\vec{x_0})(\vec{x} - \vec{x_0})+\dots\tag{1}$$ where $\mathcal{D}(\vec{f})(\vec{x_0})$ is the corresponding linear transformation.  Now (1) is nicely coordinate-independent.

Of course, nobody writes that, because those parentheses are *insane*.  But if we take a step back, we can see that each of those parenthesis is serving a purpose:

- $\mathcal{D}$ is the derivative: a map from smooth functions to ⟨something or other⟩
- $\mathcal{D}(\vec{f})$ is the derivative of a particular smooth function: $f$.  But we haven't specified *where* to take the derivative at, so $\mathcal{D}(\vec{f})$ is a map from particular points to ⟨something or other⟩
- $\mathcal{D}(\vec{f})(\vec{x_0})$ now tells us we want the derivative at $x_0$.  This is a particular linear transformation, so it is a function $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$.

Putting it together, $$\mathcal{D}\in C^{\infty}\to(\mathbb{R}^m\to(\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n))$$  In your case, the gradient, $n=1$, so we can just write: $$\nabla\in C^{\infty}\to(\mathbb{R}^m\to(\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}))$$  There's a convenient notation for this: for a vector space $V$, let $V^*$ be the space of linear functions $V\to\mathbb{R}$.  Then \begin{gather*}
\nabla\in C^{\infty}\to(\mathbb{R}^m\to(\mathbb{R}^m)^*) \\
\nabla l\in\mathbb{R}^m\to(\mathbb{R}^m)^* \\
(\nabla l)(f)\in(\mathbb{R}^m)^*
\end{gather*}

So what is this $V^*$?  Well, recall that the defining characteristic of a Hilbert space is an inner product.  This inner product gives you a way to turn elements of $v$ into elements of $V^*$: if $v\in V$, then $(w\mapsto\langle v,w\rangle)\in V^*$.  (In coordinates, this is the transpose.)  In fact, the transpose goes both ways: [all the elements of $V^*$ are of this form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).  So it's common to identify $V$ with $V^*$ (although you cannot do this if you have more than one Hilbert space at once).  Once you identify $V$ with $V^*$, then your inner product can take two elements of $V$…or an element of $V$ and an element of $V^*$…or an element of $V^*$ and an element of $V$…or two elements of $V^*$.  In the $V^*\times V$ case, you can unravel what I said above to get $$\langle\phi,v\rangle=\phi(v)$$

Based on (1), what you want to show is actually $$(\nabla l)(f)(g)=\sum_j{\frac{\partial l(f)}{\partial f(x_j)}g(x_j)}$$  But nobody writes that, because we're allergic to parentheses, and we write the equivalent $$\langle(\nabla l)(f),g\rangle=\sum_j{\frac{\partial l(f)}{\partial f(x_j)}g(x_j)}$$ instead.

Comment: Can you expand on image of the derivative $(\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}))?$ I can connect the third bullet point to $(\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}),$ but I am missing the connection between the second bullet point and what is written. Also, does this style of notation have a name? I have seen it elsewhere, but not sure what it is commonly called?

Comment: Does it mean the space of maps from $\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n})?$

Comment: @sunspots: Yes: $\mathbb{R}^m\to(\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n)$ is "maps from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to (maps from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$)."  C.f. [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) maybe?

Comment: @sunspots: The image of the derivative as a map is the set of all functions that are the derivative of some other function.  Unfortunately, I can't be more precise than that, because there are [some well-known topological obstructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms), and I don't really know topology.

Comment: But I can say: if $m=n=1$, then $(\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}^1)\cong\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathcal{D}\in C^{\infty}\to(\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R})$.  This says: fix a smooth function ($C^{\infty}$) and point ($\mathbb{R}^1$) and you get a number.  In that context, you just integrate the numbers to undo $\mathcal{D}$, so the image is "all integrable functions in $\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}$."

Comment: In higher dimensions, I think you can use the machinery of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) to get [something similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem), but one needs to learn that machinery first, and the process can take up a whole graduate course (!).

Comment: Thanks for the insight and remarks. In regard to the derivative as a map, how do we express a higher order derivative, such as the second derivative, as a map?

Comment: @sunspots: Keep stacking parens.  For ex., the next term in the Taylor expansion is $\mathcal{D}^2(\vec{f})(\vec{x}_0)(\vec{x})(\vec{x})$.  In terms of calculation methods, one strategy is that ["vectorizing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) the derivative matrix identifies $(\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n)\cong\mathbb{R}^{mn}$.  Then you can pretend $\mathcal{D}f$ is another smooth map from $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^{mn}$, so that $\mathcal{D}^2f\in(\mathbb{R}^m\to(\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^{mn}))\cong(\mathbb{R}^m\to(\mathbb{R}^m\to(\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n)))$.

Comment: Is it worthwhile to enlarge the domain of the derivative to $C^{k},$ where $k < \infty,$ so the functions are not necessarily smooth?

Comment: @sunspots: Sure; that's probably more correct than what I wrote.  I just went with $C^{\infty}$ to minimize the amount of notation I had to explain.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If $n=1,$ then the next term in the Taylor expansion is $\nabla^{2}(f)(\vec{x_{0}})(\vec{x} - \vec{x_{0}})(\vec{x} - \vec{x_{0}}),$ so it can be written as $\langle \nabla^{2}(f)(\vec{x_{0}})(\vec{x} - \vec{x_{0}}),  (\vec{x} - \vec{x_{0}})\rangle,$ since $\nabla^{2}(f)(\vec{x_{0}})(\vec{x} - \vec{x_{0}})$ is an element of the dual space?

Comment: @sunspots: Yup, that's the idea!